# IIS7: Removing Virtual Directory Leaves Child Applications?

Tags: iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior from IIS or not.

I have a setup where I have a Virtual Directory with an Application underneath it.  This gets created automatically by opening a solution in Visual Studio which references the web application (web service project, although I don't think that matters).

I removed the VD in IIS, and expected to open Visual Studio and have it prompt me to create create the VD/App again (as it does when it's not found in IIS).  This didn't happen.

I tried creating the VD manually (through IIS) with the same name, and after doing so the App was still there.  I then deleted the App first, then the VD, and reloading Visual Studio produced the expected prompt to create the VD/App.

Is this expected behavior for IIS, that the App can remain even when its parent VD is removed?  I'm not sure if this is expected, a bug in IIS, or something wrong with my machine.